# Solving the quantum an-harmonic oscillator pertubatively?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory, anharmonic-oscillators

### Background

Generally while solving the quantum an-harmonic oscillator:

$$ -\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + k_1 x^4 y + k_2 x^2 y= E y   $$

Most people (I've googled) on the internet always solve this using:

$$ \underbrace{-\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}  + k_2 x^2 y}_{H_o y} + \epsilon \underbrace{k_1 x^4 y}_{H' y} = E y   $$

Where $H_o$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian and $H'$ is the perturbation.

However, I thought of first using a **smart-ansatz**,

$ y= \exp(- \sqrt k_1 |x|^3/3) \alpha(x) $

where $|x|=$ to the modulus of x. Hence, 
$$  y''=  \begin{cases} 
 (k_1 x^4 \alpha - 2x \sqrt k_1 \alpha - 2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha' + \alpha'') e^{(- \sqrt k_1 x^3/3)} & x \geq 0 \\
      (k_1 x^4 \alpha + 2x \sqrt k_1 \alpha + 2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha' + \alpha'') e^{( \sqrt k_1 x^3/3)} & x \leq 0
   \end{cases}
$$

Substituting in the an-harmonic oscillator equation:

$$ - \alpha'' \pm 2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha' \pm 2x \sqrt k_1 \alpha   + k_2 x^2 \alpha = E \alpha $$

My idea is to now apply perturbation theory:

$$ \underbrace{- \alpha''  \pm 2x \sqrt k_1 \alpha   + k_2 x^2 \alpha}_{H_o \alpha} \pm \epsilon \underbrace{2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha'}_{H' \alpha} = E \alpha $$

We can recognize that the series is $H_o$ is the shifted harmonic oscillator.

### Questions

How do I calculate the solution to the unperterbed piecewise differential equation?

$$   (E + k_1/k_2) \alpha =  \begin{cases} 
- \alpha'' + k_2(x - \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2 \alpha & x \geq 0 \\
      - \alpha'' + k_2(x+ \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2 \alpha & x \leq 0
   \end{cases}
$$

How does one **calculate the second order pertubation**?

$$E^1 =  0 $$

(See my attempt for why)

How do I calculate the **radius of convergence** of the resulting perturbation series?

$$   (E + k_1/k_2) \alpha =  \begin{cases} 
- \alpha'' + k_2(x - \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2 \alpha - \epsilon 2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha' & x \geq 0 \\
      - \alpha'' + k_2(x+ \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2 \alpha  + \epsilon 2 \sqrt k_1 x^2 \alpha' & x \leq 0
   \end{cases}
$$

If it is not, **how does it compare asymptotically** to the general approach? Also is there any **deeper meaning to this** (getting another harmonic oscillator $+$ perturbation term upon substitution with $ e^{- \sqrt k_1 |x|^3/3)}  \alpha(x) $ )?

### My Attempt

For the unperterbed case:

$$ \alpha^{0}_n = \begin{cases} 
 H_n(x - \sqrt{k_1}/k_2) \exp(- \sqrt k_2(x - \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2/2) & x \geq 0 \\
 H_n(x + \sqrt{k_1}/k_2) \exp(- \sqrt k_2 (x + \sqrt{k_1}/k_2)^2/2) & x \leq 0
   \end{cases}
$$

Where $H_n$ is the n'th hermite polynomial.

We note $\alpha$ must be an even function as $y$, $\exp(-|x|^3)$ are even functions. The pertubation however is odd! Integrating the even functions over an odd operator we get:

$$ \alpha = \alpha_o^n + \epsilon \alpha_1^n + \epsilon^2 \alpha_2^n + ... $$

$$E^1 = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \alpha^o_n H' \alpha^o_n dx = 0 $$

Now we apply 2nd order pertubation theory:

$$ E^2 = \sum_{n \neq m} \frac{|<\alpha_o^n | H' | \alpha_o^m >|^2}{E^0_n - E^0_m} $$

... Still working on it

Comment: What happens to the ground state eigenfunction (as a vector in Hilbert space) of the free Hamiltonian when you multiply by $e^{x^3}$ ?

Comment: I mean it is not a square integrable function.

Comment: Note that that change doesn't fix the problem, but simply moves it to the other side of the real line.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ... I think your talking about $x \to X $ however there is also a substitution of $e^{-x^3} \alpha$ which yields to a different term to perturb (I would think this should make a difference).

Comment: The point is that if your prefactor is an exponential of an odd polynomial then the square-integrability conditions for alpha  become asymmetric and generally ugly.

Comment: There I made it into the modulus of x making it an even function ... Will that work?

Comment: @Qmechanic .... This isn't a homework question or a question from a book ... I was just generally wondering about my approach ... So is it alright if I remove the homework tag?

Comment: Hi Anant Saxena. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Absolute values are never a good thing if you're after Taylor series, and you need to be careful with the derivatives at $x=0$ as some terms will be discontinuous or even distribution-valued. Proceed with care, is all.

Comment: I'm not sure that your ansatz is that smart, sorry. First, the absolute value makes the second derivative of $\alpha(x)$ discontinuous at $x=0$ (since we know that $y(x)$ is a smooth function). This will make everything messy and complicated. Second, if you set $\epsilon=0$, you are back to the unperturbed problem in **both** cases. This means, for example, that the unperturbed solution for $\alpha(x)$ will be $\alpha_0(x) = \text{e}^{\sqrt{k_1}\left|x\right|^3/3} y_0(x)$. I did not do the calculation, but I expect that the solution for $\alpha(x)$ will simply undo your ansatz order by order.

Comment: @StevenMathey I did some of my own calculations and I get: $ \alpha_o = A_o \exp(-\kappa (x-\sqrt k_1/k_2)^2 $ for $x>0$ and $\alpha_o = A_o \exp(-\kappa (x+\sqrt k_1/k_2)^2 $ for $x<0$ ... where $ \kappa $ is a constant.

Comment: If you are interested in different ways to do perturbation theory, I recommend that you look into [this](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/30/7/10.1063/1.528326). The idea is simple and nice. There is a good lecture online [here](http://pirsa.org/index.php?p=speaker&name=Carl_Bender) and [this](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-yQXwhE6iWMC&dq=carl+bender&source=gbs_navlinks_s) book will contain even more details.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I assumed that $\epsilon$ in your second equation is the same as in the sixth. Then the perturbation series are different.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812211